# How can I change the main menu and default window size, plus where right click menus/hover menus appear? (Raspberry Pi 3a+)

Tags: ssh, vnc, pi-3a+

I recently started using VNC connections using RealVNC viewer (and sometimes I occasionally use SSH) and now my main menu size, default window size and position, and hover/right click menus are messed up. They appear tiny, and the hover/right click menus appear near the top left (same as the windows). How can I revert this back to normal?

Comment: What OS? Do you have a screen on the Pi?

Comment: @Milliways I use the basic raspberry pi OS, and I have it connected to a HDMI monitor. I'm currently trying to reinstall the OS though.